# How do I find a radio button by value to check it with another element - VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I apologize for the title being a little hard to understand. I had a hard time explaining it in one line. But here's what I'm trying to do.

I'm developing a screen within my app that supports a barcode gun reader. Barcode guns can only interact with textfields. And then through a text field(hidden) I can pass a custom barcode that instructs the UI to do something. Here is the UI explanation for clarity:

1. I have a radio button group with 2 options (yes and no)
2. I have a hidden textfield to accept the barcode gun read
3. I have a barcode for "yes" and another for "no"
4. If I scan the "yes" barcode, the radio button option with value = "Yes", should be checked
5. If I scan the "no" barcode, the radio button option with value = "No", should be checked

I initially thought that by changing the v-model to the correct value, it will do it, but it didn't check it. Likewise, by changing the v-model.value to true or false it will check to its appropriate value. But no cigar.

My idea on how this would work is by (pseudocode)

1. if querySelector with name ragrouphidden.value = "Yes" then find the option whose value is Yes and option.checked = true
2. else if querySelector with name ragrouphidden.value = "No" then find the option whose value is No and option.checked = true

The "find" part is what eludes me, or maybe there is an easier way.

Here's some relevant code

**Template**

```
<div>
    <q-input
        class="hidden-field"
        v-model="ragrouphidden"
        name="ragrouphidden"
        @change="raSelectOption()">
    </q-input>
    <div>
        <label class="col-6 text-weight-medium">Mark for Remote Adjudication</label>
        <div>
            <q-option-group
                v-model="ragroup"
                :options="raoptions"
                @check="raRules($event.target.value)"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Script**

```
data() {
    return {
        ragrouphidden: "",
        ragroup: null,
        raoptions: [
            {
                label: "Yes",
                value: true
            },
            {
                label: "No",
                value: false
            }
        ],

    }
},
methods: {
   raSelectOption() {
        setTimeout(() => {
            let hasFocus = document.querySelector("input[name=ragrouphidden]");
            hasFocus.focus();
        }, 500);

        if (
            document.querySelector("input[name=ragrouphidden]").value === "*yes*"
        ) {
            this.ragroup.value = true;  //this is what I need
        } else if (
            document.querySelector("input[name=ragrouphidden]").value === "*no*"
        ) {
            this.ragroup.value = false; //This as well 
        }
    },
}
```

Hopefully it makes sense to you guys. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think model value should be set like `this.ragroup = true;` instead of `this.ragroup.value = true;` have you tried that once?

Comment: Good point. Let me try. BRB

Comment: Oh for crying out loud! lol...That simple! lol. Thanks man. Put an answer in. I'll give you the credit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use `ragroup.value` to set the model value here. You can simply do `this.ragroup = true;` and vue will automatically set the `q-option-group` selected value for you behind the scene.

A simple demo with dynamic checkbox:

```js
var demo = new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: {
    checked: [],
    categories: [{ Id: 1 }, { Id: 2 }]
  },
  mounted(){ this.checked = [2] }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="demo">
  <ul>
    <li v-for="c in categories">
      <input type="checkbox" :value="c.Id" :id="c.Id" v-model="checked" />
        {{c.Id}}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```